# Closure issue with callback

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm having a Closure issue with a callback.

every time I call this function I get that `tmp` equals 1.
and I'm setting it inside the callback..

why is it happening? and how can I solve it?

```
var tmp = 1;

var getConnection = function() {

    console.log(tmp);

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        tmp = 2;
    });
};
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? This looks like the classical async issue. You are updating a global variable from within an asynchronous callback... trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = 1; // set tmp to 1

var getConnection = function() {

    console.log(tmp); // log current value of tmp

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        tmp = 2; // set tmp to 2
    });
};
```

I don't see `getConnection()` being called, but let's assume you call it immediately after declaration.

What happens in `getConnection()` is you 1) log current value of `tmp`, then 2) try to connect to Mongo, and then 3) set the value of `tmp` to 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think some data is missing in order to answer your question.

My guess is that you call `getConnection()` function in some kind of a loop, e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    getConnection(i);
}
```

In this case, the serial code (i.e. the loop and the `console.log(tmp)`) will be executed before all of the callbacks, in your case:

```
function(err, db) {
    tmp = 2; // set tmp to 2
}
```

'1' will be always presented, because the value will be updated to '2' only **after** it was written to the console.

Answer (score 0):

`MongoClient.connect` is an async operation so, if you want to use the updated value of `tmp` you should do something like:

```
var tmp = 1; // set tmp to 1

var getConnection = function(callback) {
   var ctx = this; //or whatewever you want the context to be
   console.log(tmp); // log current value of tmp

   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
     tmp = 2; // set tmp to 2
     callback.call(ctx, tmp); //you have to choose the context
  });
};

getConnection(function(tmp){
   //do some magic with tmp
})
```

By the way having `tmp` as a global variable is not such a good idea, it may be polluted by others and can cause many problems

Comment: What does the variable `ctx` refer to here? It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: there is a comment that specifies you have to choose the context `ctx` that you want.